# Hide wish list button if already added

Tags: magento2

I want to remove wishlist icon from product list and detail page if already exsist in wishlist

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$wishlistHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data');

if($wishlistHelper->isAllow()){

$wishlistCollection = $wishlistHelper->getWishlistItemCollection();     
foreach ($wishlistCollection as $_wishlist_item) {
   $in_wishlist = false;
   if ($_product->getId() == $_wishlist_item->getProduct()->getId()) {
       $in_wishlist = true; break;
   }
}
?>

if(empty($_in_wishlist)){ ?>
     <li><a href="<?= $wishlistHelper->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?= __('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please upvote these answer if useful